# I don't know why it's an empty list? max()

Tags: python

```
# Plot the highest score in history
def draw_best(background):
    ip = 'redis-16784.c89.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com'
    r = redis.Redis(host=ip, password=1206, port=16784, db=0, decode_responses = True)
    scores = [eval(i) for i in list(r.hgetall('2048').values())]
    best_scores = max(scores)
    scoreSurf = BasicFont01.render('Top score：{}'.format(best_scores), True, (0, 0, 0))
    scoreRect = scoreSurf.get_rect()
    scoreRect.width = math.floor((rate - 0.15) / 2 * screen.get_width())
    scoreRect.height = math.floor((1 - rate2) / 3 * 2 * screen.get_height())
    scoreRect.topright = (math.floor(0.9 * screen.get_width()), math.floor(0.05 * screen.get_height()))
    py.draw.rect(screen, background, [scoreRect.topleft[0], scoreRect.topleft[1], scoreRect.width, scoreRect.height], 0)
    screen.blit(scoreSurf, scoreRect)
```

I think the problem is in these two lines:

```
    scores = [eval(i) for i in list(r.hgetall('2048').values())]
    best_scores = max(scores)
```

The error it showed me was:

> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: Evidently `r.hgetall('2048').values()` is empty.

Comment: the use of eval() also doesn't seem correct, but I guess it depends on what is expected to be in the database under that hash.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it seems like `list(r.hgetall('2048').values())` is a blank sequence/list/array.

Check if it is really empty by defining a variable with the value `list(r.hgetall('2048').values())` and then print it out to check.

There is a `default` keyword that may be helpful. It will return a value if the list is empty. It works as follows:

```
my_list = []

result = max(my_list, default=None)

print(result)  # It will print "None"
```

You already think that the problem exists in those two lines, then what better way to solve this is to check if it is really in those two lines!